# Using process.communicate after popen fails

Tags: python, ssh, process, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to send command using ssh spawn to remote machine.
I'm sending the command using `Popen()` and I can see the command was done but after that I'm trying to use `communicate()` (to close the session and get a return code) and the program get stuck.

```
cmd = """expect -c 'spawn ssh -o LogLevel=quiet """ \
      """-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey """ \
      """-o ConnectTimeout=10 -2 -o CheckHostIP=no -i {0} {1}@{2} ;\
      """expect "#";send "mkdir test9\n" ;interact'""".format(self.sshKey, SSHUser, self.hostname) 
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p_stdoutdata, p_stderrdata = process.communicate()
```

When I'm reaching the communicate the program gets stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Popen` to call `ssh`.  Instead, use a library that does it all in-process in Python, such as the excellent [Paramiko](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko).  In your case it might look something like this:

```
import paramiko

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy())
client.connect(self.hostname, 22, SSHUser, password)

sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(client.get_transport())
sftp.mkdir("test9")
sftp.close()

client.close()
```

Comment: How can i send SSHkey instead of password?
How can i get a return code that way? and if i need other commends send by the user?

Comment: Please read the docs (http://docs.paramiko.org/).  Other commands can be executed by `client.exec_command()`.  You can pass `key_filename` instead of `password` if you like.  And as for how to get a return code, I'm not sure what you mean, but if you are asking how to find out if `mkdir` failed--it will raise an exception.